# Office 2003 Service Pack 3- Not able to install

Tags: windows-server-2003, microsoft-office

I am trying to install Office 2003 SP3 on a windows 2003 EE server (used as a terminal server) which already have office 2003 SP2.

I am getting an error that says "Update can not be applied".

Below are the eventviewer entries for Application:

Event Type: Warning 
Event Source: MsiInstaller 
Event Category: None 
Event ID: 1015 
Date:  1-2-2010 
Time:  5:51:22 
User:  Domain\domainadmin 
Computer: TER01 
Description: 
Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x800401F0

Event Type: Information 
Event Source: MsiInstaller 
Event Category: None 
Event ID: 11708 
Date:  1-2-2010 
Time:  5:52:23 
User:  Domain\domainadmin 
Computer: TER01 
Description: 
Product: Microsoft Office Professional Edition 2003 -- Installation failed.

Data: 
0000: 7b 39 30 31 31 30 34 30   {9011040 
0008: 39 2d 36 30 30 30 2d 31   9-6000-1 
0010: 31 44 33 2d 38 43 46 45   1D3-8CFE 
0018: 2d 30 31 35 30 30 34 38   -0150048 
0020: 33 38 33 43 39 7d         383C9}

Event Type: Information 
Event Source: McLogEvent 
Event Category: None 
Event ID: 257 
Date:  1-2-2010 
Time:  5:52:23 
User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
Computer: TER01 
Description: 
Would be blocked by access protection rule  (rule is in warn-only mode) (Common         Standard Protection:Prevent common programs from running files from the Temp folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the link 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295823 , I downloaded the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility.

Remove previous installation and reinstalled Office 2003 with SP3. Everything works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is quite clear:

> Event Type: Information Event Source: McLogEvent Event Category: None Event ID: 257 Date: 1-2-2010 Time: 5:52:23 User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Computer: TER01 Description: Would be blocked by access protection rule (rule is in warn-only mode) (Common Standard Protection:Prevent common programs from running files from the Temp folder).

You don't have permission to run the upgrade under your current security policy. I'm taking a guess that you've put the installer file in a temp folder.

Try logging in as Administrator and running the installer from another location.

Comment: That's not quite correct. The message states "Would be blocked by access protection rule (rule is in warn-only mode)": this means the rule *would* block that if it was fully enforced, but it isn't, so that message is only diagnostic.

Comment: I am having Domain Admin permission and Domain Admin is in Administrator group of Server. So no issues with permission i believe.....

Answer (score 0):

Office 2003 setup/patching should also save a set of log files in the machines defined temp folder (or the installing user's Local Settings\Temp folder), it should have a fairly obvious name.

Alternatively, you should be able to extract the SP3 installer to get it's component files, the command line to extract to a SP3 folder under C:\temp without installing should be something like:

```
Office2003SP3-kbnumber.exe /T:c:\temp\sp3 /C
```

This should leave you with the .msp patch files, ohotfix.exe installer, ohotfix.ini configuration file and a DLL in the folder you specified. Copy that whole folder to the server, then open up ohotfix.ini and towards the bottom of the file you can see the logging options, turn these on/up and re-run the service pack install by running ohotfixe.exe - it should now give you much more info on why it's failing.

Also I presume you know that being a terminal server you should be running any installs through Add/Remove Programs -> Add New Programs as per [How to install Office 2003 or Office XP on a computer that is running Windows Terminal Server](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/828955).

Comment: Hi there,

I extracted the SP3 installer and then tried to upgrade. It failed again...Similar Application errors in event log.

Comment: Did you check that all the logging options are turned on in the ohotfix.ini ? What did you see in the log files saved in the temp folder on your server?